# How to display location on markers of google maps when clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have extracted the latitude and logitude from my database tables and have shown it on the google maps with markers.Now I want to get location to be displayed on the markers when they are clicked.I tried a lot but couldn't find the way.Can you please suggest how shall I proceeed?I am also giving the sample code which may help you.Kindly help me out.

```
<?php
   $dbname='140dev';
   $dbuser='root';                              
    $dbpass='root';      
    $dbserver='localhost';
    $dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
       mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets1");
$res =  mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$lat_d = $res['geo_lat'];
$long_d = $res['geo_long'];

// mimic a result array from MySQL
$result = array(array('geo_lat'=>$lat_d,'geo_long'=>$long_d));

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="API_key"&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        // Set static latitude, longitude value
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_d; ?>, <?php echo $long_d; ?>);
        // Set map options
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        // Create map object with options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    <?php
        // uncomment the 2 lines below to get real data from the db
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets1");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['geo_lat'].", ".$row['geo_long']."), 
map);";
    ?>
    }


    function addMarker(latLng, map) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

var contentString = latLng.lat() + " , " + latLng.lng();

geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[1]) {
    map.setZoom(11);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });
    infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  } else {
    alert('No results found');
  }
 } else {
  alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
 }
 });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
 });
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:550px; border:0px #000 solid;">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:950px;height:700px;border:solid black 1px;">       
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check info windows: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: I have tried adding info windows.But it is a static way but i want dynamically to display location or atleast lat long on markers.

Comment: I mean that add infowindow for each marker. If you click a marker, its infowindow will be shown, on another marker, that marker's infowindow will be shown. Isn't that what you want from _dynamically_?

Comment: but info window must be defined statically so it can't function in dynamic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improve your `addMarker()` function as it shows lat-lng values of clicked marker on infowindow:

```
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    var contentString = latLng.lat() + " - " + latLng.lng();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much.Its working.Can you suggest a last solution for me.How can I convert this lat long an maps with actual location?

Comment: If you mean address by _actual location_, it is called geocoding and google has a nice document on it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding . Also many questions with answers in SO with geocoding tag will lead you to the solution easily.

Comment: I will go through it and let you know soon.

Comment: I have editted the code above for getting location instead of lat long values on markers using reverse geocoding but it is not working.Kindly go through it and suggest changes

Comment: I edited my post, but you need also to include `geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();` at the top of the `initialize()` function and `var geocode;` after `var map;`

Comment: Sorry,the suggested edits are also not working.Now its not even displaying the info window for lat long values

Comment: When I debugged it is giving error on line 43 i.e. "latlng not defined" which is on line geocoder.geocode()....

Comment: I am waiting for your response

Comment: 1. Your main question was different, and you are unchecking accepted answer because I didn't answer your another question in comments, that is unfair, of course you are free to change your mind but this case it is unfair. 2. I'm not your employee, if I have time, I will be happily try to answer your questions. However, your approach is not true, if you have another question, then ask it on SO, I'm not the only one person in SO. 3. You have to try more, internet has huge amount of information about this subject, you may not always get answers in your expected time.

Comment: Ok sorry for the disturbance.But anyways you helped me a lot.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add location info as marker label. Just follow the example 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/basic.html