# Reverse Geocoding not displaying info window on markers when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have extracted the latitude and logitude from my database tables and have shown it on the google maps with markers.Now I want to get location to be displayed on the markers when they are clicked.I used reverse geocoding with info windows but couldn't get the expected result on clicking the markers. When I debugged it is showing error "latlng not defined". The error is on line 43 i.e geocoder.geocode(....).Can you please suggest how shall I proceeed?I am also giving the sample code which may help you.Kindly help me out.

```
<?php
   $dbname='140dev';
   $dbuser='root';                              
    $dbpass='root';      
    $dbserver='localhost';
    $dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
       mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets");
$res =  mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$lat_d = $res['geo_lat'];
$long_d = $res['geo_long'];

// mimic a result array from MySQL
 $result = array(array('geo_lat'=>$lat_d,'geo_long'=>$long_d));

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="API_key"&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
var geocoder;
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        // Set static latitude, longitude value
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_d; ?>, <?php echo $long_d;?>);
        // Set map options
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        // Create map object with options
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    <?php
        // uncomment the 2 lines below to get real data from the db
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweets");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        //foreach($result as $row) // <- remove this line
   echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$row['geo_lat'].", ".$row['geo_long']."), 
   map);";
    ?>
    }

   function addMarker(latLng, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });

 var contentString = latLng.lat() + " - " + latLng.lng();

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: contentString
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
           } else {
              alert('No results found');
           }
        } else {
           alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
     });
 });
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:550px; border:0px #000 solid;">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:950px;height:700px;border:solid black 1px;">    
</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try position : new google.maps.LatLng(latLng);

Comment: It even didn't display the markers which previous code atleast displayed.Is there any other alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of your earlier question [How to display location on markers of google maps when clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294038/how-to-display-location-on-markers-of-google-maps-when-clicked)

Comment: declare latlng global and then try...its problem of variable scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{'latLng': latlng}` latlng is out of scope from what I can see it is only declared inside `initialize()` function.

You need a `google.maps.LatLng` instance in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `latlng` to geocoder which must be `latLng` according to your `addMarker()` function:

```
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
```

`latLng` here and,

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
```

`latlng` here which is undefined. It should be:

```
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
```